# How can I read .mp3, .pdf or .jpg file in C

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I want to read mp3 file for copy it to contents[19000].Then, I want to send contents[19000] to socket.

But, in strcat(contents, tmp), segmentation fault is occur.

But, if i read HTML file, this code operate without any problem.

How can I read .mp3 file and copy it's content to contents[19000] ??

size of mp3 file is 8MB.

```
FILE *fp;
if ( (fp = fopen("./test.mp3", "rb")) == NULL) {
  fputs("Cannot open input file...\n", stderr);
  exit(1);
}
char tmp[1024]="";
char contents[19000]="";

while (!feof(fp)) {
  fread( tmp, 1, 1023, fp);
  strcat(contents, tmp);
}
```

Comment: It is a binary file. Why strcat? Anyway, check an example also for block reading with fread

Comment: `strcat` returns a `char *` pointer to destination string after concatenation; You missed collecting it.

Comment: @suneric no, it's binary  data and return value anyway is same as first parameter. Moreover fread will not set any NIL so it will fail even for bigger text files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

strcat() is used to concatenate strings. MP3:s are binary files (you even open them as 'rb'). 
From the man:

> The  strcat() function appends the src string to the dest string,
>   over-    writing the null byte ('\0') at the end of dest, and then
>   adds a termi-    nating  null  byte.   The  strings may not overlap,
>   and the dest string    must have enough space for the result.

strcat() has no idea of the size of "tmp" and if there is no null bytes (0x00) in tmp, it will continue to read until it crashes (after reading on the stack).

Use memcpy().

Answer (score 0):

You should not use `strcat()` as it expect a C style string which should be terminate by a null character.  You should use `memcpy()` or `memmove()` and calculate the offset by yourself.